# Passing date to a function in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Calendar } from 'react-date-range';
import axios from 'axios';
import Grids from './containers/Grids/Grids';
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {process_vch: []};
  }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.handleSelect(this.props.date) (
  axios.get('http://localhost:4200/api/process',{params: {this.props.date: date._d}})
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ process_vch: response.data });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
)
}


  render() {
      return (
      <div className="App">
        <Calendar
           onInit={this.handleSelect}
           onChange={this.handleSelect} />
        <div>DropDown</div>
        <Grids data={this.state.process_vch}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What I am trying to do here is pass the date to the handleSelect function on app initialization and fetch the data from the back-end but the error I am having is this.handleSelect is not a function.

Comment: There is no handleSelect() function declared in you example, so that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: You need to declare handleSelect function

Comment: Could you please elaborate and tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use onInit method passed throught props you should use in your component class `this.props.onInit()`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simple example to handle functions on events.

```
class SayHello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {message: 'Hello!'};
    // This line is important!
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    alert(this.state.message);
  }

  render() {
    // Because `this.handleClick` is bound, we can use it as an event handler.
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Say hello
      </button>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point to figure out how things work will be to create the handleSelect  function and log the date

```
....
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { process_vch: [] };
    }

    handleSelect = (date) =>{
        console.log(date);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
.....
```

Comment: I binded  the function with the ES6 arrow callback and it worked, i really have no idea what is the concept behind this exactly and would try to figure that out, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in following ways

You can make ajax call directly in componentDidMount

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Calendar } from 'react-date-range';
import axios from 'axios';
import Grids from './containers/Grids/Grids';
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {process_vch: []};
  }

 componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:4200/api/process',{params: {this.props.date: date._d}})
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ process_vch: response.data });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}


  render() {
      return (
      <div className="App">
        <Calendar
           onInit={this.handleSelect}
           onChange={this.handleSelect} />
        <div>DropDown</div>
        <Grids data={this.state.process_vch}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

OR ES6 - Move your ajax call functionality to ES6 arrow function and call the function in componentDidMount

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Calendar } from 'react-date-range';
import axios from 'axios';
import Grids from './containers/Grids/Grids';
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {process_vch: []};
  }

componentDidMount() {
  this.handleSelect(this.props.date);
}

handleSelect = d => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:4200/api/process',{params: {d: date._d}})
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ process_vch: response.data });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}


  render() {
      return (
      <div className="App">
        <Calendar
           onInit={this.handleSelect}
           onChange={this.handleSelect} />
        <div>DropDown</div>
        <Grids data={this.state.process_vch}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

OR ES5 - Move your ajax call functionality to ES5 normal function and call the function in componentDidMount

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Calendar } from 'react-date-range';
import axios from 'axios';
import Grids from './containers/Grids/Grids';
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {process_vch: []};
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }

componentDidMount() {
  this.handleSelect(this.props.date);
}

handleSelect(d) {
  axios.get('http://localhost:4200/api/process',{params: {d: date._d}})
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ process_vch: response.data });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}


  render() {
      return (
      <div className="App">
        <Calendar
           onInit={this.handleSelect}
           onChange={this.handleSelect} />
        <div>DropDown</div>
        <Grids data={this.state.process_vch}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```